Chrome redirecting typos and other errors to registrars
My laptop got into a state where I had to reinstall from the hard drive. I did this, installed Chrome, LibreOffice, GIMP, CoffeeCup Site Designer, VS Code, and a few more apps - nothing controversial. I was busy setting up my laptop when I get a call asking for information. I looked for a particular file with no success - no worries - just recreate it!
I have an PERL script I wrote two decades ago that I have updated here and there and it does exactly what I want for modeling budgets. Sound exciting? I use it in my business constantly.
The problem is a multi-part, however, I am only confused by just part of the problem.
If in Google Chrome I type perldev.com, it redirects me to http://www.domainduck.net/images/Slide1.JPG where it should tell me that the site cannot be reached. It is a registered domain name but does not resolve to a web site.
I have used perldev.com in my hosts file, DNS, to connect to a PERL development test bed on my web server for two decades. The problem is that I would have to change a bunch of PERL scripts to reflect a new domain name if I were to change perldev.com to something else on my web server. So naturally, I am reluctant. While I can fix why the domain does not resolve to my webserver, part 1, I am concerned why any domain name - right or wrong - would redirect to a registrar, part 2. I tested non-sense domain names such as microsoft.net and got redirected to another domain registrar. For every domain name that should have a problem, such as non-existing, or a typo, or does not resolved, I got redirected to different registrars.
My next thought was to scan my computer for viruses. I used Avast and Avira and found not errors.
I want real errors and not redirects.

perldev.com is a registered domain name and has an A record.  However, this is not Chrome specific.  It happens in Firefox as well.  It appears that registrar has shutdown and whoever took over is not consistently redirecting to the image stating that domainist.com is offline.

Granted. The point I was making is that there were three cases of errors I tested and the result was the same. It is not just that site. Microsoft.net was doing the same thing the other day (for example). I realize that microsoft.net redirects to microsoft.com but still I got redirected to yet another domain registrar. I am sure this is not what Microsoft has in mind.

Please list the specific domains that you believe are "unregistered" so we can help you verify / track down what's going on. Neither perdev.com or microsoft.net are unregistered.

I think you miss the point. It is not just "unregistered domains". It is some registered domains, typos, redirected domains, and so on. The criteria is any situation where there is a redirect or an obvious error. Everything else works just as it should.

How I am looking at this is: an adware or something took over Chrome and is selectively redirecting me to different registrars. I am confused because the installs are clean - OS and a few well knowns apps so I should not have any adware or viruses. In fact, two anti-viruses say I am clean. Sometimes, these things are not found while some online scan sites may be able to solve the problem. I was looking to see if anybody knew of anything specific. Cheers everyone!! I was clearly not clear in my question.

The domain perldev.com is in fact not "unregistered" - checking the whois results for it shows it's been registered since July 2003, and is currently handled by enomdomains.com.
With that in mind, looking at the DNS for the domain shows an A record pointing at 64.98.135.1 for both perldev.com and www.perldev.com. Inspecting the response from http://perldev.com using curl or a plethora of other tools, shows that we're returned an HTTP 302 Found response, with the Location header pointing at http://www.domainduck.net/images/Slide1.JPG, as you've identified. It seems that the host isn't serving HTTPS (it times out).
This isn't something strange on your computer - it's the internet working correctly (even if unexpectedly).

I have used perldev.com in my hosts file, DNS, to connect to a PERL development test bed on my web server for two decades.

In all honesty, this is your mistake and you shouldn't have done that, for exactly this reason - just because a domain isn't registered when you first obscure it locally, doesn't mean it'll keep returning NXDOMAIN to suit your needs...
.local is reserved for this sort of thing, or you could look into using a domain you control (possibly with "Split-Horizon DNS" if you have internal services and records that you don't want to make public).
... but there's nothing stopping you from just setting up your hosts file again, and effectively obscuring your access to the real perldev.com.

I tested non-sense domain names such as microsoft.net and got redirected to another domain registrar.

microsoft.net is owned my Microsoft, and redirects to microsoft.com ... if you're getting redirected for domains that are genuinely supposed to return NXDOMAIN (i.e: they're not registered), then this could feasibly be happening anywhere from your computer (yes, some anti-virus packages do bad things like this in the name of "safety") through to your ISP (though that's considered bad behaviour if they are indeed doing this). To check if it's local to you, use nslookup or dig from a remote host, or use a web-based version.

In all honesty, this is your mistake and you shouldn't have done that... I had the workspace since before the domain name was registered. All I have to do is reboot the router to make it work. This is not the point. The point is, for three cases or errors I would expect to see, something familiar I get redirected to one of several domain registrars. I have dumped cache and anything I can think of.

"I had the workspace since before the domain name was registered." - this is irrelevant, you still shouldn't have done that

"The point is, for three cases or errors I would expect to see, something familiar I get redirected to one of several domain registrars" - please see my comment on your question
